# Eclipse build path warning

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, buildpath

I can not deploy my Java EE app on GlassFish as I have this build path warning on the Problems view:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Classpath entry
>   eclipse.fproj.jdt.libprov.osgi/jpt.jpa is marked for publish/export
>   but is not exported on the project classpath. Classpath visibility
>   within Eclipse and at runtime will
>   differ.   declaration-reglementaire-dao       P/declaration-reglementaire-dao Classpath
>   Dependency Validator Message

And this one:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Facet version for Enterprise
>   Application project declaration-reglementaire-ear must be 5.0 to
>   contain Java EE 5.0 project
>   declaration-reglementaire-serviceweb. declaration-reglementaire-ear       P/declaration-reglementaire-ear Enterprise
>   Application Validator Message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it. I had it marked as a Java EE module dependency, but I didn't have it selected for export. In the project properties window I went to Java Build Path > Order and Export and placed a check next to the entry for OSGi Bundels (JPA).